# Expand and Collapse specific row after selected in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement the expand/collapse table view cell. It's working good for many rows; they can be expanded and collapsed after clicked.

But what happen is when my table view has only one row; when I click it and then all the rest of the rows are expended too even though they are empty.

Here my code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(selectedIndex ==  indexPath.row){
        return 100;
    }else{
        return 44;
    }
}
```

// Display in cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CommentTableCell";
    //-- try to get a reusable cell --
    CommentTableCell *cell = (CommentTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    //-- create new cell if no reusable cell is available --
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    VocabularyController *vc;

    // Display word from database else display vocabulary when searching
    if (tableView != self.strongSearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        vc = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else{
        vc = [self.filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    cell.nameLabel.text = vc.korean;

    return cell;
}
```

// Selected Cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
        selectedIndex = -1;

        NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
        NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        return;
    }

    if(selectedIndex >= 0){
        NSIndexPath *previousPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:selectedSection];
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:previousPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    // Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

// I would like show my screen shot. 
[image]

How to expand only selected row when there is only one result after search? How to keep the other empty stay the same !

Thank for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change that behavior for a one row table -- the table shows the cell dividers based on the height of that one row. If you don't want this look, then I think you have to set the separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone. You could make a custom cell that has a line at the bottom to mimic a cell separator if want to see a line only at the bottom of filled cells.

Comment: I have tried that already. It's doesn't help.
my search result tableview contain only one row, when I click on that row it expanded good but the rest of other rows are expanded too.
How to solve this problem?
Thank

Comment: @MabKaaKoo, what did you try? If you do self.strongSearchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;, you should not see any separators, no matter how many rows there are. Are you saying you did that, and you still see row separators?